# How java volatile primitive variables are read from the main memory?

Tags: java, multithreading

I started reading about volatile, I get to know that threads will read variables from the main memory instead of their own stacks.

This sounds logic for reference type objects where the objects inside the threads stacks will point to the JVM heap so if we modify the object inside the heap, the references inside stacks will point to the new object.

But for primitive types, values are directly stored inside stacks, there's no track of them inside the heap so how come we talk about accessing the main memory in this case?

Does this mean that when we declare a primitive variable as volatile it will be stored in the heap instead of each thread stack?

Comment: "But for primitive types, values are directly stored inside stacks" that's true of _local_ variables, but volatile isn't something you can apply to local variables, only fields. You have to get the object from the heap to read its field value.

Comment: Where a primitive variable is stored in Java is an *implementation detail.*  That means you shouldn't have to know or care whether it's stored on the heap or the stack, because it will have no effect on your programming effort.

Comment: Just to understand your level of understanding: there are a _lot_ of `volatile` explainers on the web that are easily found with google/duckduckgo, which ones have you already read (that cover primitives, of course) and what did they not cover that still leads you to ask about the behaviour of this (pretty well documented) keyword?

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks, I haven't paid attention to that, it makes sense now.

Comment: @AndyTurner: The examples given [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-volatile) all refer to `static volatile`.   Are you sure those are stored on the heap?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Are not all field values stored on the heap? A local variable cannot be `static` or `volatile` and, as I understand it, it's only primitive local variables whose values are stored on the stack.

Comment: How have none of the [existing Questions & Answers](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+volatile+heap+stack&t=osx&ia=web) not addressed your question?